# Storyboard or not

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am porting app code from another language and tool that already fully manages all logic for switching views.

The app will probably have about 10 unique scenes for now, but most likely just grow and grow over time :)

It appears the default now is to mash it all together in one big storyboard and code file and use builtin mechanism for swiching scenes.

As I am new to iOS/Swift/Xcode I am not sure what long-term feasibility is of these solutions:

- Create unique storyboatd for each scene containing only one scene and switch manually
- Create a nib? single scene for each scene and switch manually
- Put everything together in one big storyboard and swich manually

My worries about putting everything together are at this point these:

- App startup time
- Xcode slugginish if it has to show 10+ scenes at the same time in the storyboard

Comment: `1)` You can use multiple Storyboards and link them using Storyboard reference. No manual switching required. `2)` 10 unique "scenes" is small.

Comment: `3)` storyboards and auto-layout can cause eternal headaches and sorrow

Answer (score 4):

What apple recommends is to use Storyboard, and simply switch between Views using segues just ctrl+Drag between views to create a segue and then call programmatically.

[apple developer reference: Using segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html)

Nothing is sluggish you can use as many views per storyboard as you want. if there is like 25 views, xcode maybe become slow somehow.

Enjoy

Comment: Note: The UI is built dynamicly (not by loading code, but by reading configuration files) so anything can open anything. I don't know beforehand which menu items will be available and which will open what.

Comment: @Tom if you're loading a ton of stuff from config files... then I would just avoid storyboards all together and programatically create stuff. That way you save yourself from the auto-layout nightmare and you have infinitely more flexibility (I *really* hate storyboards). I would sit down and write a full page essay about why I hate storyboards, but at the end of the day it's still a really subjective question.

Comment: There are schools for that. I personally would believe that code is made for logic, not for UI. However there are a lot of people who prefer using code as they feel more control. There is one drawback for storyboard for me which is the source control. Its like nightmare for the team to work on the same storyboard since its an XML File after all

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of subjective, but:

- App startup time

This is a non-issue. Storyboards are compiled down to XIBs so they're about the same as using NIBs performance-wise. And NIBs are plenty fast enough for most use cases.

- Xcode slugginish if it has to show 10+ scenes at the same time in the storyboard

Not really. My Macbook is six years old and I have Storyboards with far more than ten screens. I find screen real-estate to be a far bigger issue than performance. With Xcode 7 you can also use multiple Storboards and link them together.